# Moved from WordPress to ASP.NET-MVC-5, How to dropped WordPress url completely

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, wordpress, url

I moved from WordPress to ASP.NET-MVC-5 about 3/4 months ago. But Google has refused to drop urls of WordPress.

How do I get Google to drop all WordPress urls currently not on my asp.net site?

Please note:
1. I moved without redirecting from WordPress to asp.net 
2. Same domain name
3. Similar content, but different structures, so no redirection

Comment: You can remove old URLs  by using Google Webmastertools

Comment: This could work only for a period of ninety days.... I need those urls gone permanently.